# Dynamic links in symfony2 based on a model

Tags: symfony, twig

How can I use a class (that is returned by a factory service) and one of it's methods to determine whether a link should be displayed or not?

I could easily inject it via the `$this->render` method but it's a link used for several pages and I'd have to inject it to many controllers that use the same template manually.

Is there another way I can access the factory in a twig template?

The service I want to use looks something like this:

```
$factory = $this->get('somefactory');
$model = $factory->build('somemodel', new SomeClass()); //SomeClass() is the first       parameter in $model's constructor
$model->returnsABoolean(); //Determines if link should be showed or not.
```

Comment: Make a twig extension, inject your model then add a twig function to access it.

Comment: @Cerad Of course. I've never had to use custom extensions until now. Care to post that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a twig extension, inject your model then add a twig function to access it.

```
namespace Cerad\Bundle\AppBundle\TwigExtension;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $model;

    public function getName() { return 'cerad_app_extension'; }

    public function __construct($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(            
            'cerad_check_link' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'checkLink'),
        );
    }
    public function checkLink($link)
    {
        return $model->shouldLinkBeVisible($link);
    }
}
```

services.yml:

```
cerad_app.twig_extension:
    class:  Cerad\Bundle\AppBundle\TwigExtension\AppExtension
    arguments:  
        - '@model_or_factory_service_id'
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Twig template:

```
{% if cerad_check_link(link) %}
  {# Show it #}
{% endif %}
```

It's all in the documentation.

Comment: Care to add an example of an extension returning a boolean to use it in a template? :) If not I'll just add it as an answer later, but I'll still accept your answer :D

Comment: Wow.  A drive by down vote 3+ years after the answer was accepted.  Admittedly I'd probably consider using a voter for this but I don't think they had voters back then.  Or maybe I just pissed someone off.  It happens.